# Comparing proportions from dependent samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion

I'm trying to compare the proportions of word referents by word type within subjects.

My variables are word type (Word1 or Word2) and referent type (Object or NonObject). I counted for each subject how frequently they used Word1 and Word2 and how often such words referred to objects.
My hypothesis is that the rate of Word1 referring to an Object is higher than the rate of Word2 referring to an Object.

I settled on proportions because I don't think I can compare raw frequencies because Word1 occurs much more than Word2.

For example: Subject 22 used Word1 200 times (140 in reference to Objects, 60 in reference to NonObjects). The same subject used Word2 10 times (2 in reference to Objects, 8 in reference to NonObjects).
So the data might look like this:

| sub | word | total | object_referent | proportion_object |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 1 | 200 | 140 | 0.7 |
| 22 | 2 | 10 | 2 | 0.2 |
| 23 | 1 | 170 | 102 | 0.6 |
| 23 | 2 | 6 | 2 | 0.33 |

One other issue is that the proportions for each word type are not normally distributed.

Searching online keeps giving me variations of Chi-squared tests but those don't apply here. And I don't think I can do a t-test because I don't meet the normal distribution assumption.
Someone suggested I do a regression predicting Object from WordType but I don't understand how to incorporate proportions into that.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: > "Searching online keeps giving me variations of Chi-squared tests but those don't apply here". ... Why do you think that?

Comment: My understanding is that chi-squared looks at proportions across a sample (e.g. the proportion of the group that responds in X way) but here I want to compare proportions as a within subjects factor (compare the proportion of time an individual does X to proportion they do Y but averaged? across all individuals in the sample). But if there is a type of Chi square that can do that please let me know